# Loading screen without XML - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So, I am making game in Android Studio, and instead of `android-layout` I am using `Java class` as a engine and `contentView`.

```
 spaceInvadersEngine = new SpaceInvadersEngine(this, size.x, size.y);
    setContentView(spaceInvadersEngine);
```

Now, while I load new level I need something to pop out and make screen unclickable until level loads all data. (In my head I have something like a banner that will be on the center of the screen).
But, I do not have a `XML file` for `spaceInvadersEngine` so I can't put for example `ImageView` that will be visible while data is loading.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Create an `imageView` programmatically and set visibility property to `gone`, example : `yourImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

sample :

```
           // Initialize a new ImageView widget
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            // Set an image for ImageView
            iv.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.animal));


            // set visibility to gone
            iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Finally, add the ImageView to your layout layout
            yourLayout.addView(iv);
```

- *need something to pop out and make screen unclickable until level loads all data*, you can use AsynTask Class, it has 3 methods first `doInBackground` that you can use to loads all data. After all data loaded it will pass return value to another method called 'onPostExecute' which you can use set imageView to hiding again after you show it on method `PreExecute`

Sample :

```
 public class LoadImageViewWhileLoadData extends AsyncTask<Boolean,String,Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show your imageView
        yourImageView.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... booleans) {
        // your code that loads all data
        // must return value that pass to onPostExecute
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // you can use this method if you use progres bar instead of imageview
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {

        // make it gone again.
        yourImageView.setVisibility = View.GONE;
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
    }
}
```

Comment: `AsyncTask` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) its better not to encourage its Use any further.

Comment: I do not have a layouts. I have two threads, and on one I have method draw where I draw all bitmaps